# Search/Replace regex in Eclipse when text is broken up over multiple lines?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

Due to some of formatting rules, we have some code that will look like this in Eclipse:

```
      this._log
      .error(
         this,
         "Some error text");
```

And sometimes it's on one like like

```
this._log.error(this, "more error text");
```

I need to do a search/replace to get rid of the first "this" parameter and the comma, so using the second example, it would become

```
this._log.error("more error text)
```

I was using something like

```
log\.error.*\(.*this.*,
```

for the search, and just

```
log\.error(
```

as the replacement text. This search worked fine when it was one one line, but the search doesn't find the first occurrence, so I'm looking for help on what regex would find it? Specifically I am looking for "the word 'log followed by a dot followed by possibly spaces then a left paren followed by possibly spaces then the word 'this' then possibly spaces then a comma" regardless if it's on one or more lines, just in that order.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse follow these steps:

1. Press <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> to open `Find/Replace` dialog
2. Select `Regular Expression` checkbox under `Options`
3. In `Find:` textbox enter this regular expression: `log\s*\.\s*error\s*\(\s*this\s*,\s*`
4. In `Replace:` textbox enter this text: `log.error(`